# How to check continuous url calling from anonymous IP

Tags: performance, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-security

i am working on wcf using c#, using "webHttpBinding" and "mexHttpBinding" for my API's.

```
<endpoint address="wcf" behaviorConfiguration="NewServiceBehave" binding="webHttpBinding" name="webp" contract="Project.INewService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Hosted at server under ('HTTPS'), using my clients publicly. how to trace/capture the continuous url calling from anonymous users IP.

Comment: Can you provide an example when you say to capture continuous url?